# python string format with negative sign for negative number, but space for positive number

Tags: python

Is there a format code to format -2.34 as '-2.3', but +2.34 as ' 2.3' (notice the leading space)? Basically show the negative sign but leave a space for positive sign.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number_sign

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use " " (a space) to insert a space before positive numbers and a minus sign before negative numbers:

```
txt = "The temperature is between {: } and {: } degrees celsius."

print(txt.format(-3, 7))
```

answer :

```
The temperature is between -3 and  7 degrees celsius.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `format` on `float`:

```
>>> "{: .1f}".format(+2.34)
' 2.3'
>>> "{: .1f}".format(-2.34)
'-2.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using f strings it can be done very succintly:

```
MYSTR = 2.34
print(f'{MYSTR:{".1f" if MYSTR < 0 else " .1f"}}')
```

Comment: nested expressions.  nasty.  dig it!

Answer (score 0):

```
f = lambda i: " %.1f"%i if i > 0 else "%.1f"%i

pos = 2.358
neg = -2.358

print(f(pos)) # " 2.3"
print(f(neg)) # "-2.3"
```

Comment: Better: simply `"% .1f" % i` (note that I shifted the whitespace after the '%' character), see https://pyformat.info/#number_sign